# Asp.net - Do changes to session objects persist? 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the session to hold a custom object UserSession and I access the session like this:

```
UserSession TheSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] as UserSession;
```

Then, in my code, I modify a property of TheSession like this

```
TheSession.Prop1 = some new value;
```

My question is this: when I change the value, does it change the value inside the session that's in HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] or just the TheSession variable, in which case I'd need to reassign the object variable to the session.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard session provider is a simple dictionary that stores objects in memory.

You're modifying the same object that you put in the session, so the modifications will persist.
(unless you're using an [evil mutable struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil))

Comment: I'm declaring TheSession object like this: public class TheSession {...} Am I in the clear?

Comment: That's a class, not a struct.

Comment: ok, cool; thanks for your clarification, very much appreciated. I'll never use a struct:)

Comment: I'm not saying to never use a struct; I'm saying to never use a **mutable** struct.  (one that can change)

Comment: ok, I'll keep that in mind: use a struct if its content is never intended to be changed (let me know if that's right).

Comment: Not **able** to be changed. And only if it's reasonably small (4-8 bytes), and represents a value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is the same object.  It is very easy to see in the following example:

```
Session["YourObject"] = yourObject;
yourObject.SomeProperty = "Test";
var objectFromSession = (YourObjectType)(Session["YourObject"]);
Response.Write(objectFromSession.SomeProperty);
```

The `Write` will display: `Test`

Answer (score 1):

create a static class with static properties:

```
public static class UserSession
{
    public static int UserID
    {
         get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]); }
         set { Session["userID"] = value; }
    }
}
```

When u use it:

```
UserSession.UserID = 23;
Response.Write(UserSession.UserID);
```

it will use the session variable to store information passed to this property.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to reassign the object. Because both of them are pointing to same instance in memory