# c# asp.net object reference lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, object-reference

hello i m doing a very simple Asp.net application project

```
 namespace WebApplication1
 {
 public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {
    market m = new market();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void button_clickSell(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {


        float price = float.Parse(this.BoxIdPrezzo.Text);

        m.insertProd("xxx", 10, "yyy");
        m.addOfferForProd("ooo", 5, "gggg");
        m.insertProd(this.BoxIdDescrizione.Text,price,this.BoxIdUtente.Text);
        String s;
        m.outMarket(out s);  
        this.Output.Text = s;  //the output here work good
        this.Output.Visible = true;

    }
    protected void button_clickView(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        String s;
        m.outMarket(out s);
        this.Output.Text = s;  // here seem to have lost the reference to product why?
        this.Output.Visible = true;
    }
}
}
```

the problem is that when i click on button1 which call button_clickSell everything works good but when i click on button2 which call button_clickView products seem to not be anymore in the Market object, but this is pretty strange because in market object i have a list of product  and  m.outMarket in the first time work propely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because of how pages work. Every time you make a request or a post-back to the page the values will be lost in that variable.

You will need to hold that in a session or something similar.

Here is a very basic example of using a session.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Collection"] == null)
        {
            Session["Collection"] = new List<int>();
        }//if
    }
    protected void button_clickSell(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> collection = (List<int>)Session["Collection"];
        collection.Add(7);
        collection.Add(9);
    }
    protected void button_clickView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> collection = (List<int>)Session["Collection"];
        collection.Add(10);
    }
```

Comment: ok please can you make an example ? how do i store them in a session ? point me to a link ?

Comment: I added a basic example of a session. You should read up on them a bit more if you have never seen them before.

Comment: i think it should be like this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380842/asp-net-do-changes-to-session-objects-persist

Comment: if i store everything in a databse it is odd or it makes sense ?

Comment: I can't really answer that. Depends on how you want to build your application. I can say it is very normal to store data in a database for a web based application.

Answer (score 0):

you can view this post on MSDN: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Comment: if i store everything in a databse it is odd or it makes sense ?

Comment: there are many ways to stone the data:Session,Cookie,Cache or Database. You can find some posts to campare them.

Answer (score 0):

> `Session` should be used when information is required across the
>   pages. Now the matter for the two buttons lying on the same page. So
>   ViewState is Best option.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (ViewState["Collection"] == null)
     {
            ViewState["Collection"] = new List<int>();
     }//if
}
protected void button_clickSell(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<int> collection = (List<int>)ViewState["Collection"];
     collection.Add(7);
     collection.Add(9);
}
protected void button_clickView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<int> collection = (List<int>)ViewState["Collection"];
     collection.Add(10);
}
```